# How to get user activities from interaction in Discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I get the `activities` from `interaction.options`? If I use `interaction.options.getUser`, I receive the following error:

```
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'activities')
```

Here is my code:

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');

const activity = user.presence.activities.type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)s don't have a [`presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence) property, only `GuildMember`s have. What you can do is to `fetch` the member by its ID first:

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user);
```

And then, you can get the [`activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities):

```js
const activities = member.presence?.activities;
```

`activities` returns an array of [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity), so you'll need to grab the first one for example to log its `type`:

```js
console.log(activities[0]?.type)
```

Please note that you'll need to have the `GUILDS`, `GUILD_MEMBERS`, and `GUILD_PRESENCES` intents enabled!